# rebinning of data

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I have a datafile with results from measurements that describe a two dimensional distribution. The file is in a contour plot format, i.e. in the first column a variable x is fixed and in column 2 y runs over its full range; column 3 contains the functional value f(x,y). Then x is increased, y runs again over the full range and so on:

```
x1    y1   f(x1,y1)
x1    y2   f(x1,y2)
x1    y3   f(x1,y3)
.......
x2    y1   f(x2,y1)
x2    y2   f(x2,y2)
x2    y3   f(x2,y3)
........

xn    y1   f(xn,y1)
xn    y2   f(xn,y2)
.....
```

The databins are very narrow and I would like to rebin them into broader bins, both in x and y. I could do this by DO loops and IFs. Is there are faster, more elegant way to do this? 
Here is a simple example before rebinning:

```
0.05      -0.95      10
0.05      -0.85       9
0.05      -0.75       7

0.10      -0.95       15
0.10      -0.85       13
0.10      -0.75       12
```

Here the numbers in the 3rd column give numbers of counts. The numbers in the 2nd column give the middle points of intervals, i.e. -0.9 -> -1, -0.8 -> -0.9, -0.7 -> -0.8. Now I want to increase the width of the bins in the second column from 0.1 to 0.3 and the number of counts in these new bins should be the average over the original values. Thus, the table should look like:

```
0.05        -0.85     26/3
0.10        -0.85     40/3
```

How can this be done with Mathematica built-in commands?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Can you give a small example of before and after, for what you'd like to accomplish? I have no doubt, however, that this could be accomplished in another manner than using Do's and If's

Comment: see `GatherBy` .

Comment: @user6014: the x-values give the middle point of a certain interval in x, same for y, and f(x,y) is really the number of counts in these intervals. All the values of x and y are equidistant. I would just like to make the intervals broader. So a set of data such as

Comment: So here is a very short numerical example (unfortunately, my data files are much larger):

    0.05      -1.0           10
    0.05      -0.95           8
    0.05      -0.9             7

    0.10      -1.0             9
    0.10      -0.95           8

Answer (score 4):

There are two possibilities I can see. The first (and IMHO the best) is to use 
[`ArrayResample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayResample.html). Unfortunately, it doesn't do *exactly* what you want, and I couldn't get it to work on your small data snippet. However, I suspect it does something better, and on large data sets it gives very similar output.

The second possibility (which, unfortunately, I wrote before I knew about `ArrayResample`) is the function

```
rebin[data_, newbins_] := Map[Mean@Flatten[#, 1] &, 
  Partition[SplitBy[data, First], newbins, newbins, {1}, {}], {2}]
```

which gets the averaged midpoints and counts that you requested for your data. I'll explain what it does below.

### Examples

First, let me give a demonstration. Suppose you have a large data set in an `n × 3` array:

```
data = Flatten[Table[
      {x, y, IntegerPart[100 x Sin[2 π (x + y)] Cos[2 π (x - y)]]},
     {x, 0, 1, 0.01}, {y, 0, 1, 0.01}], 1];

(* The full data *)
ListPlot3D[data, Filling -> Bottom, InterpolationOrder -> 0]

(* Downsampling by `rebin` *)
ListPlot3D[Flatten[rebin[data, {5, 5}], 1], Filling -> Bottom, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 0]

(* Downsampling by `ArrayResample` *)
ListPlot3D[
  Flatten[ArrayResample[SplitBy[data, First], {20, 20, 3}], 1], 
  Filling -> Bottom, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Clearly the outputs are very similar, but not identical. The main difference is that `ArrayResample` uses far more sophisticated resampling techniques than `rebin`.

`ArrayResample` can't get very far with your example data because it needs at least two sample points per dimension. With `rebin` we get:

```
data = Partition[Flatten[ImportString[string, "Table"]], 3];
rebin[data, {1, 3}]

(* {{{0.05, -0.85, 26/3}}, {{0.1, -0.85, 40/3}}} *)
```

### General explanation of `rebin`

I would recommend using `ArrayResample` if you can. FWIW I'll go through a  general example with `rebin`, in case it can be useful in some way. Suppose that your data looks something like this:

```
rawdata = Flatten[Array[{x[#1], y[#2], f[##]} &, {6, 6}], 1]

(* {{x[1], y[1], f[1, 1]}, {x[1], y[2], f[1, 2]},... , {x[1], y[6], f[1, 6]}, 
    {x[2], y[1], f[2, 1]}, {x[2], y[2], f[2, 2]},...
    ...,  , {x[6], y[5], f[6, 5]}, {x[6], y[6], f[6, 6]}
   } *)
```

So that `Dimensions[rawdata] == {36, 3}`, rather than `Dimensions[rawdata] == {6, 6, 3}`, as it would be without that `Flatten`. This is the format it will be in if you use @HenrikSchumacher's `ImportString`.

We want to get it into a structured format with all the `x`-values gathered together -- the `{6, 6, 3}` format above. (If it's already in this format, then great -- you can skip this). That can be done with [`SplitBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplitBy.html):

```
MatrixForm[
  structureddata = SplitBy[rawdata, First]
]
```

[image]

Now suppose that you want to rebin your data into bins twice as wide in `x` (so that `x[1]` and `x[2]` bins go together, `x[3]` and `x[4]`, etc.) and three times as wide in `y` (`{y[1], y[2], y[3]}` are all together, `{y[4], y[5], y[6]}` are all together, etc.). Then we can [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) it with:

```
xbins = 2; ybins = 3;
MatrixForm[
  partdata = Partition[structureddata, {xbins, ybins}, {xbins, ybins}, {1}, {}]]
]
```

[image]

(I'll explain about those extra parameters in a minute).

Next, we just use [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) at level 2 to take the average:

```
MatrixForm[
  Map[Simplify@Mean@Flatten[#, 1] &, partdata, {2}]
]
```

[image]

Those extra parameters in `Partition` -- the `{xbins, ybins}, {1}, {}` -- are in case the rebinning doesn't nicely line up with the dimensions of the data. For example, suppose we want the same rebinning, but the data doesn't fit as nicely:

```
rawdata = Flatten[Array[{x[#1], y[#2], f[##]} &, {7, 7}], 1]
```

Then those last `x` and `y` values will be rebinned by themselves:

```
MatrixForm[
 Map[Simplify@Mean@Flatten[#, 1] &, 
  Partition[
   SplitBy[rawdata, First], 
    {xbins, ybins}, {xbins, ybins}, {1}, {}], 
 {2}]
]
```

[image]

You still end up with the desired rebinning, but it still seems like an arbitrary decision -- why not isolate the first values? In fact there are many such problems associated with rebinning data. `ArrayReshape` could be your best bet for dealing with them consistently.

Comment: many thanks for this extensive answer. I will need some time to digest it. Btw: the problem I mentioned arises because a program produces output in a form suitable for making contour plots with gnuplot (my initial example).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the most efficient solution but easy to implement. First, we import the data that you gave as a `String`:

```
string = "0.05      -0.95      10
  0.05      -0.85       9
  0.05      -0.75       7

  0.10      -0.95       15
  0.10      -0.85       13
  0.10      -0.75       12";
data = Partition[Flatten[ImportString[string, "Table"]], 3];
```

This results in an array of size $n \times 3$. The following will duplicate the first two entries in each row as often as the third row tells us:

```
pts = Flatten[Map[ConstantArray[#[[1 ;; 2]], #[[3]]] &, data], 1];
```

That means, `pts` looks probably like the orginal raw data that you have collected. Now you can use `BinCounts` and `Histogram3D` (with slightly differing syntax) to bin the data as you wish. As an example, this bins the points according to bins of size `dx` times `dy`.

```
xmin = -1.; xmax = 1.; dx = 0.1;
ymin = -1.; ymax = 1.; dy = 0.1;
bincounts = BinCounts[pts, {xmin, xmax, dx}, {ymin, ymax, dy}];
Histogram3D[pts, {{xmin, xmax, dx}, {ymin, ymax, dy}}]
```